# Display data by Id and the associated many-to-many table data efficiently in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My website have many posts and the detail page of each post show the associated information along with the Tag(s) [many-to-many data] the post is tagged with.

Code:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int id)
{
    var Post = await _postInterface.GetByIdAsync(id);

    var Tag = await _context.Posts.Include(p => p.PostTags)
                        .ThenInclude(t => t.Tag).ToListAsync();

    return View(Post);
}
```

- `var Post` displays database data according to the `id` selected.
- `var Tag` is initialized from the many-to-many relationship database tables.

My question:

Is there a way to initialize only the content without using `var Tag =` here as it is not required?

```cs
await _context.Posts.Include(p => p.PostTags).ThenInclude(t => t.Tag).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: If I am correct, what you want is the selected post with related tags?

Comment: @YongShun yes, you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain what you are seeing happening, a break-down of your code:

```
var Post = await _postInterface.GetByIdAsync(id);
```

This line is fetching a single post from whatever the _postInterface class is. This is commonly called a Repository Pattern and often has a shortcoming that it doesn't easily facilitate things like eager loading related data that callers might want.

```
var Tag = await _context.Posts.Include(p => p.PostTags)
                    .ThenInclude(t => t.Tag).ToListAsync();
```

This line isn't actually loading a tag, or tags, it is actually loading *ALL* Posts, with ALL included tags into the "Tag" variable and the DbContext's tracking cache. (very bad!!!)

The reason this appears to work is because after calling that "read everything" the DbContext is now tracking all posts and tags, so when you go to return the "Post" that you loaded, the proxy references to it's PostTags/Tag can be filled by the DbContext when the consuming code tries to access them. If you remove that `var Tags = ....` then the Context isn't tracking them and you get #null, or if lazy loading was enabled, it would fetch them when accessed so long as the DbContext wasn't disposed.

What you really want is:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int id)
{
    var post = await _context.Posts
        .Include(p => p.PostTags)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.Tag)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .SingleAsync(p => p.Id == id);
    return View(post);
}
```

This tells EF we want the one post, but to include that post's postTags and Tags. The `AsNoTracking()` call is optional, but makes it a tad faster in this case as it tells EF that the DbContext does not need to track these entities. If you are returning detached entities then the Context doesn't need to track the entities, as the DbContext should be disposed anyways at the end of the request. For instance if you happen to add the `.AsNoTracking()` to your original `var Tags = ....` query, you'd actually find that your code stops working because it is the tracking cache behaviour that your code is relying on to populate the references when you return "Post".

Comment: Thank you! The code needs to be added with `var Post = await _postInterface.GetByIdAsync(id);` and `await await` along with `.AsNoTracking()` needs to be removed as it gives null. Also, Thank you for explaining the code.

Comment: The point is to use that line *instead* of the GetByIdAsync() call. That method is virtually useless since it cannot eager load and there is no benefit to making 2 calls to the database. If you replace the `var post = _postInterface.GetByIdAsync()` call with the call I have above as-is, it will return your desired post and tags. If your GetById call has any additional filtering or such just add that to the above. I've corrected the example typos.

Comment: You are correct. Now the code works fine but adding `.AsNoTracking()` still results in null for many-to-many table data. Why is that the case?

Comment: It certainly shouldn't, but if you do the 2 call approach to get a Post alone, and use a 2nd query against the DbContext to load the post and tags /w `AsNoTracking` but return the first call's Post, that post instance will not resolve the Tags etc. loaded in the 2nd call due to those entities not being tracked. If you load the post and tags via the DbContext and *not* using that first call, then that returned post will have the tags many-to-many populated despite the `AsNoTracking`.

Comment: If you paste the method example above in place of your existing method it should return the many-to-many items. There should be no call to the _postInterface at all.

Comment: Yes. The code works even without `_postInterface`. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the `GetByIdAsync` method to get the selected post with related tags.

```cs
public async Task<Post> GetByIdAsync(int id)
{
    return await _context.Posts
        .Include(p => p.PostTags)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Tag)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

If you want to keep the current implementation for `GetByIdAsync`, would suggest creating another method, for example: `GetPostWithTagsAsync` with the above implementation. Don't forget to add the method (signature, without the method body) in your `PostInterface`.

```cs
public async Task<Post> GetPostWithTagsAsync(int id)
{
    return await _context.Posts
        .Include(p => p.PostTags)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Tag)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

```cs
public interface IPostInterface
{
    Task<Post> GetPostWithTagsAsync(int id);
}
```

Comment: The issue with a repository method like this is that it will now always eagerly load values when some calls may just need details about the Post. Some entities may have several related entities and if you end up eager-loading everything every time the calls are much slower/bigger than they need to be. Once you start trying to parameterize what related entities you want to eager load, and then handling methods like searches with filtering, sort orders, pagination, and eager loading it starts getting quite complex and you're better off just using the `DbSet` and Linq.